# No mouse pointer in 22.04

Tags: mouse, touchpad

My wifes 22.04 has no cursor on her laptop via the touchpad. in the past a reboot used to fix it but 5 reboots later and still no pointer showing. I can make it back to the desktop and the keyboard seems to work but there's not even a sign of the mouse pointer (EG: no icons highlight etc to indicate a invisable pointer is working somewhere in the background).

I was hoping to make it up to the settings >> accessibility and enable locate pointer but ... as mentioned cant even click on settings to open that screen. Any tips welcome.

Ive tried several suggestions on other forum posts but alot seem to be for older ubuntu versions so not sure they are relevant as they didnt work anyway

EDIT: i have installed a wireless mouse and can now navigate. When looking in settings>> touchPad and mouse settings she doesnt have any touchpad related toggles etc in there like i do on mine, so guessing her touchpad drivers have magically uninstalled ?

Comment: Make sure that it is not disabled via a Function Key + F# key.  There is usually an icon on one of the F# Keys, or possibly disabled in BIOS.  You might need to try a power reset of the system as well.  That is done by pulling all power even the battery then trying to power it on with the power button.  If the battery is not removable you power it off and hold down the power button for like 30+ seconds.

Comment: What model is the laptop in question?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1435658/edit) your question and add in details of the laptop.  There might be someone that has experienced the same thing and might be able to help.